# How to immediately force cancel an NSOperation with AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsoperation, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking in my application and I am attempting to implement a "Tap To Cancel" feature in my progress HUD. I have a singleton class that manages all of the HTTP requests. If the progress HUD is tapped, I call:

```
[[[HTTPRequestSingleton sharedClient] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

But this doesn't "cancel" the operation like I need it to. I read up on the [`NSOperationQueue` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and came across this:

> Canceling an operation object leaves the object in the queue but notifies the object that it should abort its task as quickly as possible. For currently executing operations, this means that the operation object’s work code must check the cancellation state, stop what it is doing, and mark itself as finished. For operations that are queued but not yet executing, the queue must still call the operation object’s start method so that it can processes the cancellation event and mark itself as finished.

And regarding the `cancelAllOperations` method:

> This method sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the queue. Queued operations are cancelled before they begin executing. If an operation is already executing, it is up to that operation to recognize the cancellation and stop what it is doing.

My problem seems to specifically involve an operation that is already executing, which I want to immediately cancel. With AFNetworking, how can I alert the operation that it should cancel and discard all information about the request?

**Code used for operation**

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *loginOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    //operation was successful

    if (loginOperation.isCancelled)
    {
        //can't do this. variable 'loginOperation' is uninitialized when captured by block      
    }

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

    //operation failed

}];
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem with the operations not being terminated instantly ?

Comment: The operation continues like normal, and the `success:` block is called. I'd like to find a way to prohibit that block from being called if the operation is cancelled.

Comment: btw: you can check if a request failed because of cancellation within the callback using the NSError instance like this: [error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a full morning of digging through AFNetworking source code, it turns out that the reason my operations weren't canceling had nothing to do with the operations themselves, but rather because I've been starting the operations incorrectly all this time. I've been using

```
[NSOperation start];
```

when I should have been adding it to my `HTTPRequestSingleton`'s operation queue:

```
[[[HTTPRequestSingleton sharedClient] operationQueue] addOperation:NSOperation];
```

Adding it to the queue allows it to be canceled properly without having to check the `isCancelled` property.

Answer (score 3):

> completionBlock
>
> Returns the block to execute when the operation’s main
> task is complete.
>
> - (void (^)(void))completionBlock Return Value The block to execute after the operation’s main task is completed. This block takes no
>   parameters and has no return value.
>
> Discussion The completion block you provide is executed when the value
> returned by the isFinished method changes to YES. Thus, this block is
> executed by the operation object after the operation’s primary task
> **is finished or cancelled**.

Check the operation `isCancelled` property to understand why is the callback called.

---

Look into the initialization code:

```
+ (AFJSONRequestOperation *)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                                    success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success 
                                                    failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure
{
    AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[[self alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest] autorelease];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(operation.request, operation.response, responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(operation.request, operation.response, error, [(AFJSONRequestOperation *)operation responseJSON]);
        }
    }];
    
    return requestOperation;
}
```

What you'll want to do to get the `operation` var in the callback is to use `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` after the  `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` initialization which is kind of overkill, the better way would be to copy the code and use

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[[self alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest] autorelease];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // ... here you can check `isCancelled` flag
```

Comment: OK, it's good to know about the `isCancelled` property, but how can I check that value from within the `success:` or `failure:` callback blocks? Or preferably, use that value to prohibit the `success:` and `failure:` blocks from being reached?

Comment: Don't you have the `AFHTTPRequestOperation *` var as the callbacks parameter ? you'll want to check `operation.isCancelled`.

Comment: No, the callback params for `AFJSONRequestOperation` are `NSURLRequest`, `NSHTTPURLResponse`, and `id` for the JSON object. The operation itself isn't passed into the block, so I can't figure out how to check its `isCancelled` property. I've added the code I use for the operation in the question. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: See the answer update showing how you use your own callback with the `operation` var available as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you much for your help. My problem turned out to be because of how I added the `NSOperation` to the queue but your answer was helpful.

Comment: As far as I can see the cancel does not fire the success: or failure: blocks. Check setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: in AFHTTPRequestOperation.m, where a 'cancel' returns before it gets to the success: or failure: sections

Comment: @nh32rg The documentation quote is related to `NSOperation`, not  `AFHTTPRequestOperation.m`. Normally you try not to break the logic of the base class, luckily you can look through the source code to understand what's happening in case of abnormal behavior. As we wete talking about `AFJSONRequestOperation ` I've also put a quote with its `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` at the answer, there's no dedicated logic for "isCancelled" state there (also I can only see a check of the `error` var at the current version of its implementation).