# How to stop AFHTTPRequestOperation?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

The cancel could stop the instance of AFHTTPRequestOperation, but sometimes, it will failed.

Anyone have the solution to stop the AFHTTPRequestOperation instance immediately or with seconds delay ?

Comment: could you edit your question to display a little bit of code showing how you currently cancel the request operation?  and the operation is on a thread separate from the one you're calling cancel from, right?

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361824/how-to-immediately-force-cancel-an-nsoperation-with-afnetworking

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there nothing more than following you can do with AFHTTPRequestOperation!

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFHTTPRequestOperation operationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
 [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
 [operation performSelector:@selector(cancel) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
```