# Cancel upload process in AFNetworking on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I implement app upload image from uiimagepickercontroller to server. But i want implement Cancel button in uploading process to cancel upload.

In upload function:

```
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    ProgressView.hidden = YES;
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Uploading successfull." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
    [av release];
    overlayToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"response string: %@", operation.responseString); //Lets us know the result including failures
}];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

And buttoncancel :

```
[httpClient.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

When I pressed buttoncancel,it not stop uploading process and then alertview "Uploading successful" appear.I don't know why can not stop but alertview still appear.
alertview
May you help me?

Comment: *It not work When i pressed buttoncancel.* What's not working? Any logs, anything?

Comment: Define not working.  For all you know, the operation could have completed before the action assigned to that button even fires.

Comment: It can not Stop upload process.@Rob

Answer (score 5):

You are cancelling the wrong operation queue. You are adding the operation to a brand new `NSOperationQueue`, but you are calling `cancelAllOperations` on `httpClient.operationQueue`.

If you cancel the upload on the same operation queue that you've added the operation to, it should work. This is what happens in `AFURLConnectionOperation.m` when it is cancelled:

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self.lock lock];
    if (![self isFinished] && ![self isCancelled]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
        _cancelled = YES;
        [super cancel];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];

        // Cancel the connection on the thread it runs on to prevent race conditions
        [self performSelector:@selector(cancelConnection) onThread:[[self class] networkRequestThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:[self.runLoopModes allObjects]];
    }
    [self.lock unlock];
}
```

Some more background about operation queues in general:

`cancelAllOperations` usually cancels all *pending* operations. If an operation is already in progress, it is up to the operation to cancel what it is doing (AFNetworking is handling this case).

> This method sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the
>   queue. Queued operations are cancelled before they begin executing. If
>   an operation is already executing, it is up to that operation to
>   recognize the cancellation and stop what it is doing.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/cancelAllOperations

This might help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Also, in the special case of AFNetworking, this might be interesting too: [How to immediately force cancel an NSOperation with AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361824/how-to-immediately-force-cancel-an-nsoperation-with-afnetworking)